# i am currently getting this error, System.InvalidOperationException: 'Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.'

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.DataTable

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Katlego\Documents\LoginDb.accdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from logintable where username1=@username1 and password1=@password1, conn")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username1", oleDbType:=OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtusername.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password1", oleDbType:=OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtpassword.Text
    Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Using logintable As New DataTable
        Dim unused = adapter1.Fill(logintable)
        If logintable.Rows.Count <= 0 Then
            MsgBox("error username or password")
        Else
            MsgBox("login sucessfull")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the connection first

```
conn.Open()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo when you are initializing `cmd` object. You include the conn object **inside** the connection string. So the cmd object is missing a connection object.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from logintable where username1=@username1 and password1=@password1, conn")
```

Should be:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from logintable where username1=@username1 and password1=@password1", conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to separate you user interface code (where you click buttons and show message boxes) from your database code.

`Connection`s, `Command`s and `DataAdapter`s need to be disposed so they can release their unmanaged resources. `Using...End Using` blocks will do this for us.

Since you only want to know if the record exits you can just get the count. You had a typo in your command text. The closing quote included the `conn`.

We don't need `DataTable` or `DataAdapter`. That single piece of data only requires an `ExecuteScalar` which returns an `Object` so we need the `CInt`.

```
Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    If IsLoginValid(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text) Then
        MsgBox("login sucessfull")
    Else
        MsgBox("error username or password")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsLoginValid(uname As String, pword As String) As Boolean
    Dim count As Integer
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Katlego\Documents\LoginDb.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("select Count(*) from logintable where username1=@username1 and password1=@password1;", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = uname
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pword
        conn.Open()
        count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    If count = 1 Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

There is still a big problem with the code. Passwords should **NEVER** be stored as plain text. They need to be salted and hashed but that is beyond the scope of this question.